# JS : Calling a function within a named function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am trying to get access to the named function `create` from the `testingSounder` function.  How would I go about this when they are nested named functions like this?

```
loadSounder: function() {
     var mentForm = (function (appId, locId) {
          var create = function() {
              console.log("CREATING")

          }
     })
},

testingSounder: function() {

     //How can I run the create function from loadSounder?
}
```

Comment: There are a few ways, but without more context of what sort of changes are permitted and what the structure has to be like, it's hard to say for sure (can you explain why you can't just move `create` outside?)

Comment: There is no way to do it without changing the code so that `create` is more exposed.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was asked not to change the structure. The loadSounder function has a lot of variables defined under `mentForm` that the nested `create` and other internal functions use.   But for my instances, I just need to call that inner function from my outer function, `testingSounder()`

Comment: _"I was asked not to change the structure"_  asked by whom and what exactly does that mean? What constitutes _"the structure"_?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return both functions:

```
loadSounder: function() {
     var mentForm = function (appId, locId) {
          var create = function() {
              console.log("CREATING")
          };
          return create;
     };
     return mentForm;
},

testingSounder: function() {
    this.loadSounder()("app", "loc")();
}
```

Comment: The redundant parentheses around the `mentForm` function will probably only serve to confuse

Comment: Oh yes @Phil - missed that.

Comment: It got me wondering if OP's actual `mentForm` is an IIFE but it's impossible to tell. Nice answer